# How to infer type from types map

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typeguards

I can't figure out how to ensure type-safety in the `onEvent` function.

```js
enum MyEnum {
  One,
  Two
}

type Payloads = {
  [MyEnum.One]: { iAmOne: string; one: number };
  [MyEnum.Two]: { iAmTwo: string; two: number };
};

interface BetEvent<ENUM extends MyEnum> {
  type: ENUM;
  payload: Payloads[ENUM];
}

const onEvent = (ev: BetEvent<any>) => {
  if (ev.type === MyEnum.Two) {
    ev.type; // should be MyEnum.Two
    ev.payload; // should be { iAmTwo: string; two: number };
    ev.payload.iAmOne; // should throw Error
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

```
enum BetEventType {
  One,
  Two
}

type BetPayloads = {
  [BetEventType.One]: { iAmOne: string; one: number };
  [BetEventType.Two]: { iAmTwo: string; two: number };
};

type BetEvent = {
  [T in BetEventType]: {
    type: T,
    payload: BetPayloads[T]
  }
}[BetEventType]

const onEvent = (ev: BetEvent) => {
  if (ev.type === BetEventType.Two) {
    ev.type; // is BetEventType.Two
    ev.payload; // is { iAmTwo: string; two: number };
    ev.payload.iAmOne; // gives compile error
  }
};
```

[Demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20BetEventType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20One%2C%0D%0A%20%20Two%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20BetPayloads%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BBetEventType.One%5D%3A%20%7B%20iAmOne%3A%20string%3B%20one%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%5BBetEventType.Two%5D%3A%20%7B%20iAmTwo%3A%20string%3B%20two%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20BetEvent%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BT%20in%20BetEventType%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20BetPayloads%5BT%5D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%5BBetEventType%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20onEvent%20%3D%20(ev%3A%20BetEvent)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(ev.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20BetEventType.Two)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ev.type%3B%20%2F%2F%20is%20BetEventType.Two%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ev.payload%3B%20%2F%2F%20is%20%7B%20iAmTwo%3A%20string%3B%20two%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ev.payload.iAmOne%3B%20%2F%2F%20gives%20compile%20error%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A)

I know there is an accepted answer but this one is undoubtedly better because...

1. No runtime overhead (meaning no addition in compiled code which is going to be executed)
2. Better `BetEvent` type because it is nice union of all possible event types (hover to see what I'm talking about)

You should consider marking this as accepted

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement Type Guard docs[enter link description here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

But first you have to declare union of events:

```js
type Events = BetEvent<MyEnum.One> | BetEvent<MyEnum.Two>;
```

Then let's declare guard:

```js
let enumTwoGuard = (ev: Events): ev is BetEvent<MyEnum.Two> => ev.type === MyEnum.Two;
```

Syntax `ev is BetEvent<MyEnum.Two>` means TS will change type of `ev` in if statement.

Full example:

```js
const onEvent = (ev: BetEvent<any>) => {
  if (enumTwoGuard(ev)) {
    ev.type; // BetEvent<MyEnum.Two>.type: MyEnum.Two
    ev.payload; // { iAmTwo: string; two: number; }
    ev.payload.iAmOne; // ERROR
  }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20MyEnum%20%7B%0A%20%20One%2C%0A%20%20Two%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20Payloads%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%5BMyEnum.One%5D%3A%20%7B%20iAmOne%3A%20string%3B%20one%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%5BMyEnum.Two%5D%3A%20%7B%20iAmTwo%3A%20string%3B%20two%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Ainterface%20BetEvent%3CENUM%20extends%20MyEnum%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20type%3A%20ENUM%3B%0A%20%20payload%3A%20Payloads%5BENUM%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20Events%20%3D%20BetEvent%3CMyEnum.One%3E%20%7C%20BetEvent%3CMyEnum.Two%3E%3B%20%0A%0Alet%20enumTwoGuard%20%3D%20(ev%3A%20Events)%3A%20ev%20is%20BetEvent%3CMyEnum.Two%3E%20%3D%3E%20ev.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20MyEnum.Two%3B%0A%0Aconst%20onEvent%20%3D%20(ev%3A%20BetEvent%3Cany%3E)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20(enumTwoGuard(ev))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20ev.type%3B%20%2F%2F%20BetEvent%3CMyEnum.Two%3E.type%3A%20MyEnum.Two%0A%20%20%20%20ev.payload%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7B%20iAmTwo%3A%20string%3B%20two%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20ev.payload.iAmOne%3B%20%2F%2F%20ERROR%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good solution. By using guards like this I would have to implement a new guard for every single enum.

Comment: @elderapo I think you would just make a generic guard like `let enumGuard = <E extends MyEnum>(ev: BetEvent<any>, e: E): ev is BetEvent<E> => ev.type === e;` and use `if enumGuard(ev, MyEnum.Two) {}`.